# How to control dependent PopupMenus?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I created three interdependent `PopupMenu`s with names `demographic`, `region` and `custom`:

```
DynamicModule[{demographic = "Demographic", region = "Region", custom = "Custom"},
 Dynamic@Grid@{{
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[demographic], {"Demo1", "Demo2", "Demo3"}, "Demographic"],
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[region], {"Region1", "Region2", "Region3"}, "Region"],
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[custom], {"Custom1", "Custom2", "Custom3"}, "Custom"]
     }}]
```

[image]

These controls should depend on each others' values. I want the followings:

1. `region` and `demographic` should be reset to `"Region"` and `"Demographic"` if any from `custom` is selected
2. `custom` should be reset to `"Custom"` if either `demographic` or `region` is changed

I tried it with `If` and `Which` but it still won't work. How can I control these three `PopupMenu`s?

Comment: It is always a good idea to try to make your code samples that show the behaviour in question, as short as you can.

Comment: I think you will probably find answers to similar problems have already been posted here ...but most likely this can be done within the second argument to `Dynamic`

Comment: @Subbu I've greatly simplified your question: most of it was just styling and sugar. You would get much faster and better answers if you were to put more effort into disassembling your problems to the core. In this case, it could even have been reduced to a two-interrelated-controller problem using the second argument of Dynamic of which [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6913/89) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20588/89) are a few answers. (yes I am aware of the date)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the second argument of `Dynamic`. Any function put there will be evaluated whenever the controller is changed, so it is quite straightforward to include the resetting of the other popup menus:

```
DynamicModule[{demographic = "Demographic", region = "Region", custom = "Custom"},
 Dynamic@Grid@{{
   PopupMenu[
     Dynamic[demographic, (demographic = #; custom = "Custom") &],
     {"Demo1", "Demo2", "Demo3"}, "Demographic"],
   PopupMenu[
     Dynamic[region, (region = #; custom = "Custom") &],
     {"Region1", "Region2", "Region3"}, "Region"],
   PopupMenu[
     Dynamic[custom, (custom = #; demographic = "Demographic"; region = "Region") &], 
     {"Custom1", "Custom2", "Custom3"}, "Custom"]
     }}]
```