# Control maximum value of a slider with another control

Tags: manipulate

Is it possible to make *$y_{max}$* of *Slider[y, {$y_{min}$,$y_{max}$}]* depend on another control?

For example, I have three variables (*Time, Type1, Type2*).  I want a drop down box for the user to select which type to plot.  And I want the user to have the ability to scale up and down the y value (however the maximum y value should depend on the level chosen, 150000 for Type1 and 1 for Type2).

```
mySubset = {{0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {60.`, 78069.`, 0.52046`}, {120.`, 
81417.`, 0.54278`}, {180.`, 84765.`, 0.5651`}, {240.`, 88113.`, 
0.58742`}, {300.`, 91461.`, 0.60974`}, {360.`, 94809.`, 
0.63206`}, {420.`, 98157.`, 0.65438`}, {480.`, 101505.`, 
0.6767`}, {540.`, 104853.`, 0.69902`}, {600.`, 108201.`, 
0.72134`}, {660.`, 111549.`, 0.74366`}, {720.`, 114897.`, 
0.76598`}, {780.`, 118245.`, 0.7883`}, {840.`, 121593.`, 
0.81062`}, {900.`, 124941.`, 0.83294`}, {960.`, 128289.`, 
0.85526`}, {1020.`, 131637.`, 0.87758`}, {1080.`, 134985.`, 
0.8999`}, {1140.`, 138333.`, 0.92222`}};

yTypes = {"Type1", "Type2"}
yMax = {0., 150000., 1.}
Manipulate[
 Module[{week, y},
  yColumn = (Position[yTypes, yChosen][[1]])[[1]] + 1;
  y = Part[mySubset, All, yColumn];
  week = Part[mySubset, All, 1]/10080;
  ListPlot[Transpose[{week, y}], Joined -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{startTime, startTime + window}, {0, ylim}}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Blue, 
   Background -> White, PlotStyle -> Blue, AxesStyle -> Blue, 
   ImageSize -> {550, 350}, ImagePadding -> 35]],
 {{startTime, 0.0, "Starting Week"}, 0, 1., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{window, 0.1, "Number of Weeks"}, 0.1, 52., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ylim, 150000, "y limit"}, 1, 150000, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {yChosen, yTypes},
 TrackedSymbols -> True,
 AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do this, but when you flip types, the current value of `lim` can be out of range depending on current type until you click on the slider again to correct it. But this can be easily fixed in the code if you know the scaling needed.

For example if you in `type2` and `lim` is say 100, and then click on `type1` where the max is only one, then now `lim` will be out of range. But again, you can scale this in the code, inside the same `If` you see below, so that it will be automatic as well.

```
Manipulate[

 {limMin, limMax} = If[yChosen == "Type1", {0, 1}, {0, 15000}];

 Module[{week, y},
  yColumn = (Position[yTypes, yChosen][[1]])[[1]] + 1;
  y = Part[mySubset, All, yColumn];
  week = Part[mySubset, All, 1]/10080;

  ListPlot[Transpose[{week, y}], Joined -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{startTime, startTime + window}, {0, ylim}}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Blue, 
   Background -> White, PlotStyle -> Blue, AxesStyle -> Blue, 
   ImageSize -> {550, 350}, ImagePadding -> 35]],

 {{startTime, 0.0, "Starting Week"}, 0, 1.,Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{window, 0.1, "Number of Weeks"}, 0.1, 52., Appearance -> "Labeled"},

 {{ylim, lim, "y limit"}, limMin, limMax, Appearance -> "Labeled"},

 {yChosen, yTypes},
 {{lim, 0.5}, None},
 {{limMin, 0}, None},
 {{limMax, 1}, None},

 TrackedSymbols -> True,
 AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2}
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

In the

[tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html)

there is a section called "Interdependent Controls" that has an example and some warnings about what to expect when you do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
 mySubset = {{0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {60.`, 78069.`, 0.52046`}, 
 {120.`, 81417.`, 0.54278`}, {180.`, 84765.`, 0.5651`}, 
 {240.`, 88113.`, 0.58742`}, {300.`, 91461.`, 0.60974`}, 
 {360.`, 94809.`, 0.63206`}, {420.`, 98157.`, 0.65438`},
 {480.`, 101505.`, 0.6767`}, {540.`, 104853.`, 0.69902`}, 
 {600.`, 108201.`, 0.72134`}, {660.`, 111549.`, 0.74366`}, 
 {720.`, 114897.`, 0.76598`}, {780.`, 118245.`, 0.7883`}, 
 {840.`, 121593.`, 0.81062`}, {900.`, 124941.`, 0.83294`}, 
 {960.`, 128289.`, 0.85526`}, {1020.`, 131637.`, 0.87758`}, 
 {1080.`, 134985.`, 0.8999`}, {1140.`, 138333.`, 0.92222`}};
```

With slight modification of the control `yChosen` in OP's code, one can specify the limits of `ylim` without having to introduce new controls:

```
  Manipulate[Module[{week, y},
  y = Part[mySubset, All, yChsn + 1];
  week = Part[mySubset, All, 1]/10080;
  ListPlot[Transpose[{week, y}], Joined -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{startTime, startTime + window}, {0, ylim}},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Blue, Background -> White, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, AxesStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> {550, 350}, ImagePadding -> 35]],
 {{startTime, 0.0, "Starting Week"}, 0, 1., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{window, 0.1, "Number of Weeks"}, 0.1, 52., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ylim, 1., "y limit"}, 0, {1, 1500}[[yChsn]], {.1, 1}[[yChsn]], Appearance-> "Labeled"}, 
 {{yChsn, 1, "yChosen"}, {1 -> "Type1", 2 -> "Type2"}},
 TrackedSymbols -> True, AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2}]
```

As noted by @Nasser, the value of `ylim` will be out of range as one switches between `Type1` and `Type2`. A better method is to associate two separate dynamic variables with `ylimit` and update `ylim` using the second argument of `Dynamic` inside the control `yChosen`. Using this approach, the slider `ylim` will "remember" its values associated with various values of `yChosen`.

```
  Manipulate[Module[{week, y},
  y = Part[mySubset, All, yChsn + 1];
  week = Part[mySubset, All, 1]/10080;
  ListPlot[Transpose[{week, y}], Joined -> True,
   PlotRange -> {{startTime, startTime + window}, {0, ylim}}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},  Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Blue, 
  Background -> White,   PlotStyle -> Blue,
  AxesStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> {550, 350}, ImagePadding -> 35]],
 {{startTime, 0.0, "Starting Week"}, 0, 1., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{window, 0.1, "Number of Weeks"}, 0.1, 52., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ylim, 1., "y limit"}, Automatic, 
   If[yChsn == 1, 
  Manipulator[Dynamic[j, (ylim = j; j = #) &], {0, 1, .1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"], 
  Manipulator[Dynamic[i, (ylim = i; i = #) &], {0, 1500, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]] &}, 
  {{yChsn , 1, "yChosen"}, {1 -> "Type1", 2 -> "Type2"}, 
  SetterBar[  Dynamic[yChsn , (yChsn = #; 
   ylim = If[yChsn == 1, j, i]) &], {1 -> "Type1", 2 -> "Type2"}] &},
  {{i, 1.}, None}, {{j, 1.}, None},
  TrackedSymbols -> True, AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2}]
```

Comment: Thank-you, this is great, however I did not specify in the original question that I want the script to be used for data with any number of y types and I am currently unsure how to modify your answer to do so.

Comment: @MLD, that's a good question. I don't have quick answer off the top of my head. I will update if I find an approach that works for the general case.